# console program publishing web job

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs, azure-appservice

I need to download a certificate from azure vault.  When I use this method, CertificateClient.DownloadCertificateAsync local it works. However, when a publish to Azure I get this message   Unhandled exception. System.Exception: Creating JWT bearer token failed.
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The system cannot find the file specified.   Is the problem I don't have access to key vault or I cant "download" the certification the file system/environment.  I want to say it is the file system because it runs on my local machine.  Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot?

Comment: I publish a console program as a webjob that is triggered on an Azure appservice

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that you may have a problem with accessing your `Azure Key Vault` and/or downloading the certificate.

***To troubleshoot the error, you can check the below steps:***

- Verify that the Certificate is not Expired.
- Check whether you have the proper permissions to access the `Azure Key Vault` and download the certificate.
- Ensure that the certificate exists in your `Azure Key Vault` and that the name and version are correct.
- Also check that you have the correct connection details for your Azure Key Vault, including the `correct URL`, `subscription ID`, and `tenant ID`.
- Check the network connection to your `Azure Key Vault` to make sure that it is accessible.
- Try accessing the `Azure Key Vault` using the `Azure CLI` or `Azure portal` to see if the issue is with your code or with the `Azure Key Vault`.

If you continue to experience issues, you may want to look at the logs or event viewer to see if they provide any additional information.

***C# Code to Download the Azure KeyVault Certificate***

```cs
ClientSecretCredential clientCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);  
var secretClient = new SecretClient(new Uri(keyVaultAddress), clientCredential);  
var response = await secretClient.GetSecretAsync(certificateName);  
var keyVaultSecret = response?.Value;  
if (keyVaultSecret != null)  
{  
  var privateKeyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(keyVaultSecret.Value);  
  return new X509Certificate2(privateKeyBytes);  
}  
return null;
```

Azure CLI Command to download Key Vault Certificate.

```cs
az keyvault certificate download --vault-name YourKeyVaultName -n cert-name -e `DER/PEM`
```

***Steps to publish a console program as a web job in Azure :***

- Package your console program as a deployment package, this is usually a `ZIP file` that contains the compiled executable and all its dependencies.
- Create a `web job` in Azure App Service using `Azure portal` or using the `Azure CLI` /`Powershell`.
- When you create the `web job`, you have to specify the type of web job - `continuous` or `triggered`, the `deployment package`, and any configuration settings.
- Start the web job using `Azure portal`, the `Azure CLI`, or `Azure Powershell`. You can also configure the web job to start automatically when the App Service starts.

References taken from [DownloadCertificateAsync Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.security.keyvault.certificates.certificateclient.downloadcertificateasync?view=azure-dotnet) and [az keyvault certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/keyvault/certificate?view=azure-cli-latest#az-keyvault-certificate-download)